# Purge css with certain prefix or from certain file

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-purge

I am exploring the purge CSS plugin (https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss) and I found there is a safelist for certain selectors that we don't want to remove. But, I want to remove only those CSS that start with certain prefixes and keep everything else as it was.

Thanks